# Custom Filter in Excel Interop using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm looking to filter value based upon the condition which will be less than or greater than equals a specific number in excel interop c#.

Current Code:

```
 xl_WorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets as Worksheet;
 xl_WorkSheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
 Range index = xl_WorkSheet.Range["K:K", Type.Missing];
 xl_WorkSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(11, 1, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues);
```

This code currently filters the value present in that column. But the thing here is I need the filter to perform value greater than equal 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.

I have changed this line like this :

```
 xl_WorkSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(11, ">=1", XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd);
```

And the solution is Working.